# How to call a Angular function from a Webapi return

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I am using PDFSharp in my project. I need to open a modal after it saves the document. The function to open the modal is in a Angular controller. How would I do this?

WebApi Controller

```
 // Save the document...
           const string filename = @"C:\Users\texas_000\Desktop\TexasExterior\TexasExterior\JobSetupPdfs\HelloWorld.pdf";

            document.Save(filename);
            // ...and start a viewer.
           // Process.Start(filename);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        }
        return string.Empty;
```

Function to open Modal

```
$scope.PrintPreviewModal = function () {
    $ekathuwa.modal({
        id: "PrintPreviewModal", contentStyle: "width:800px;heigth:400px",
        scope: $scope,
        templateURL: "ModalPrintPreview"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you're calling off to the WebApi controller, but I'd imagine (since you're using Angular) you're using Angular's `$http` service.

If so, just open the modal on the promise `success` at the end of the call:

```
$http.get('/SaveTheDocumentWebApiAction').success(function (){
    $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you know how to make API calls from your angular app.

After you make your api call and it returns, you want to execute $scope.PrintPreviewModal()

If you are using promises you will want to do this in the Success function that is executed when you get a 200 response code back.  I hope this helps.

```
 $scope.save = function () {
        save(params, success, error); //api call to save doc
    };

    var success = function () {
       $scope.PrintPreviewModal(); //open modal
    };

    var error = function () {
      //do something
    };
```